# Is there a default type for parameters of main in ANSI C or is gcc just being generous?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I copied an example starting with

> main (t) {

So, when compiling with gcc -pedantic I expected at least compalints about
- missing return type of main (that one came)
- missing type for 't' - nothing, neither with -Wall nor -pedantic.

Is this just a bit generous of gcc or is there a default type in the standard?
Couldn't find anything so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard makes no provision for a `main` function with 1 parameter - it requires two forms, one with 0 and one with 2. Implementations are permitted to allow others.

So, GCC is doing something implementation-dependent to allow this, even if you had specified the type.

C89 allows parameters with no declared type, defaulting to `int`. The same applies to variables and to functions with no declared return type (they return `int`). C99 doesn't allow any default `int` types (and GCC diagnoses it with `-pedantic -std=c99`).

Comment: Note that the C89 implicit int rule applies both to parameters and to functions; in your declaration, both `main` and `t` default to `int`.